# How can I access the classes inside a module from a directory in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I have a module in Android Studio called `signal-protocol-java-2.8.1` as shown in this picture :
[signal-protocol-java-2.8.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKToV.png)
I want to access the classes inside this module from a directory, in the same project. How can I do this?

Comment: You could get them from [the GitHub repository for that project](https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-java).

Comment: I have added it as a new module in ly project, but I don't know how to access it from a directory. @CommonsWare

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "access it from a directory", sorry.

Comment: Add the jar file as a dependency with gradle. `implementation files("/path/to/your/file.jar")`